# Check Disk Usage in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

How do I view the disk usage of all folders in Windows 7? I need to get the same result I would in Linux with the command `df -h`. I'm mainly interested in seeing which disk and folder is consuming the most storage space. What command can do this?

Comment: Can't you check it with KDirStat?

Answer (score 5):

I like [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/).  It gives a graphical representation of file sizes and it is easy to quickly see at a glance where and what is using the most space.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several "tools" available that provide detailed information regarding folders and their contents.  There's a list [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/113012/10-best-free-tools-to-analyze-hard-drive-space-on-your-windows-pc/).  However, the one I like is called [DiskPie](http://diskpie.software.informer.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try a program called GlaryUtillities, if you go to the advanced tab you should see a little program called Disk Explorer which lets you see what is taking up the most disk space and the percentage of every file and folder.    Hope this helps.